# Angular2 hide content until DOM loaded

Tags: angular

Is it possible to immediately run Angular2 application without showing a loading screen?
I know it is possible in AngularJS, but can not find the same thing in Angular2.

Comment: What do you mean with showing without a loading screen? The `Loading...` text node between the app (`<app>Loading...</app>`) ?

Comment: I want to make the page loaded synchronously, to render a content only after all data is loaded like a normal page - if a browser tab's loading spin has gone then a content must be shown.

Comment: Of course not "Loading..." text or even white page, but the rendered content of my app.